# Override EXE that loaded ActiveX control that created a minidump

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, activex

We have some legacy software that uses ActiveX controls.  These controls form part of an SDK for which customers use and develop software against.

If there are problems with the control and it crashes, a minidump file is created.

I have an issue and want to debug using the minidump.  However, when attempting to debug the issue, Visual Studio wants to load the customer's application.  We don't have a copy of the customer application, that's just not possible.  Is it possible to override the application that loads the control in order to debug where in the control sources the problem was caused?  How do I do that?

Comment: The minidump is meaningless without the app that causes it to occur. Somehow "overriding the application" wouldn't provide any benefit, because the minidump wouldn't properly associate with that app. You'll need to gather enough information from your client to be able to reproduce the issue in your own test app.

Comment: Normally yes.  But the minidump is generated inside the OCX. 
Aren't these controls run in their own process?

Comment: If that's the case, shouldn't you be able to just create any old app that loads the OCX and generate the issue yourself? Of course the answer is no, but in order to create an app that "overrides" the actual app, you'd need to do that anyway. The dump file isn't going to help without the original app code available. Your override app would have to be able to reproduce the EXACT conditions that caused the original app to create the minidump in order to use it, and if you can do that you don't need the minidump at all.

Comment: Here goes the painful process of debugging COM.